# Navigate between pages without changing the link

Tags: javascript, html

This question might have been asked in the past but I cannot seem to find the answer. I would like to navigate between pages without avec to redirect to a brand new `xxx.html` file. Basically, I want to keep only one `html` file being the `index.html`

In order to understand what I mean, here is a small preview of this functionality I want to achieve.

[Preview](https://gyazo.com/4f128538140f6ff00142a9e2ad647770)

As you can see, the piece of clothing is not its individual `html` file. What method is used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing here is a dynamic webpage that is taking advantage of client-side technology to create this effect. To help further explain, let's quickly go over some web development terminology:

**Client-Side:** Code that is executed on the user's computer (in this case in their web browser).

**Server-Side:** Code that is executed on a server, then a response of some sort is sent to the client.

With server-side code, the value cannot change unless a new call is made to the server to get a new response. This is because the code isn't actually running on the computer the user is running, it's running on some other computer probably thousands of miles away. However, with client-side code, dynamic changes could be made in real-time because the code is actually running on the user's computer.

When it comes to server-side code, we as developers have a myriad of options. Any language that can send an HTTP response to a web browser could theoretically be used as a server side language. In 2018, that's basically every major language in existence! That being said, some popular options today include Python, Ruby, Java, and Javascript (Node JS).

When it comes to client-side code, however, we're limited by what can run in a user's web browser. In general, modern web browsers only understand Javascript. However, while the language has gotten better over the years, writing code in pure JavaScript can sometimes be cumbersome, so there are libraries that help make writing Javascript easier (such as jQuery) and there are even languages that compile down to Javascript to add new syntax and functionality (such as Typescript and Coffeescript).

If you'd like to start writing dynamic web applications, a good place to start would be to learn the basics of [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/). Then, maybe start learning [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), or front-end libraries such as [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [React](https://reactjs.org/). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is called a Single-Page-Application. There are a lot of frameworks with which you can create a page like this. If you are going for plain HTML/CSS/JavaScript it will be a lot harder to do correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use javascript for this. Either you can load all content at once and just show/hide the content you need, or you could ajax to fetch the content and then render it without page reload.